# rbash - restrictec shell, permite al usuario ejecutar 'rm' sin yo permitirlo

Tags: linux, ubuntu

tengo un user llamado `invitado`, que tiene el `env` en `/bin/rbash`.
Tengo la lista de comandos almacenados en `/home/invitado/bin`, actualmente tiene solo esto:

```
▶ ls -ls
total 0
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 jul  3 14:57 ls -> /bin/ls
```

por tanto solo podria ejecutar `ls` , pero en cambio puede ejecutar mas comandos como `rm` o `touch` , no entiendo, si le estoy restringiendo a los que esten en dicho fichero, porque no lo hace. Es peligroso.

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta solucionado, he añadido en el `.bashrc` del user restringido lo siguiente :

```
PATH=$HOME/bin
```

De esta forma siempre ejecutara los comandos del bin de su home

Comment: Aceptar la respuesta se te olvidó?

Comment: @ICIM si la respondo yo mismo tengo que esperar 2 dias en aceptarla como correcta :)

Comment: Con configurar  `$PATH` no evitas que los usuarios puedan ejecutar otros comandos, solo configuras donde buscar cuando el usuario no especifica la ruta al ejecutar algo. Ello no impide que los usuarios puedan ejecutar cualquier cosa en el equipo, solo que hay que colocar la ruta completa, por ejemplo: `/bin/rm`.

Comment: si de verdad quieres restringir el acceso por completo, tendrias que considerar usar un `root-cage` para ese usuario.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot

Comment: @eftshift0 buenas, he hecho una prueba poniendo desde la cuena de `invitado`  : `/bin/rm fichero` y no me deja, me dice: `-rbash: /bin/rm: restringido: no se puede especificar «/» en nombres de órdenes` . Es decir, no me deja poner `/` en los comandos, con esto no deberia de poder ejecutar lo que dices no ?

Comment: Si, no conocía el concepto del _"restricted shell"_. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html Veo que tampoco podrias modificar el valor de la variable `PATH` así que de pronto es suficiente para mantenerlo bajo control.